# Implementing Do not track in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, tracking, do-not-track

How do I implement do not track browser consent from asp.net mvc3?
Do all major browsers like IE, Firefox and Chrome send some cookie consent request if the user has set do not track settings enabled in their browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Do Not Track" just means that the browser sends the `DNT` header with every request, that's all it is. It does not provide any additional client functionality. The header has a value of `1` when enabled, and either sends `0` or omits the header when disabled.

You, as a web application developer, do not need to concern yourself with the `DNT` header unless you are involved in developing visitor tracking systems, in which case the higher-ups in your organisation will tell you if you should respect the header or not.

In ASP.NET you can retrieve the header like so:

```
String doNotTrack = Request.Headers["DNT"];
if( doNotTrack == "1" ) {
    // Do not track the user
    // ...whatever that means.
}
```